# How to use postman for simple add function in python

Tags: python, postman

I am very new to python.

Recently I heard about API, REST and Postman.

I have seen using postman we can send parameters to the function and that functions will return back something.

I thought I will write a simple python function to add numbers.

This will be the code:

```
def addme(a,b):
    c = a + b
    return c
```

For this simple pure python function how can I handle postman requests and response.

I tried to directly call(POST) this function in postman with its location and giving two parameters in body header. but it won't work.

When I observed it may postman only run for programs which run on some port. So can anybody help me in understanding how to handle all the scenes for this very basic function.

I am really curious to learn from everyone at StackOverflow. And also suggest any efforts to take on this.

Comment: You need a server. I would suggest looking at a Flask tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alex mentioned, you actually need a server to be able to make things work with Postman. Below you can see a minimal example of what would be needed to execute what you are looking for.

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/addme", methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    a = request.form.get('a')
    b = request.form.get('b')
    c = int(a) + int(b)
    return str(c)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

To get this up and running you can follow the [instructions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#a-minimal-application). But essentially it boils down to

```
export FLASK_APP=addme.py
flask run
```

This assumes that the name of the file where you have the code is called `addme.py`. This will start a server on the port 5000 so you can now send a post request to the following url `http://localhost:5000/addme`

If you are looking for a proper tutorial for this I would recommend the [flask mega tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world). There is a book on flask by the same author which has taken this mega tutorial as the basis for the book.